# Optimising Probabilistic Weighted Moving Average (PEWMA) df.iterrows loop in Pandas

Tags: python, performance, numpy, pandas

I'm implementing the Probabilistic Exponentially Weighted Mean for real time prediction of sensor data in pandas but have issues with optimising the pandas notebook for quick iterations.

Is there a more optimal way to completely remove the `for` loop as it currently runs longer than expected. How can I take advantage of `apply()` ; or vectorized operations etc. here?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
#%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'retina'
#%matplotlib inline
from itertools import islice
from math import sqrt
from scipy.stats import norm


ts = pd.date_range(start ='1-1-2019',  
         end ='1-10-2019', freq ='5T') 


np.random.seed(seed=1111)
data = np.random.normal(2.012547, 1.557331,size=len(ts))
df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp': ts, 'speed': data})
df.speed = df.speed.abs()
df = df.set_index('timestamp')
time_col = 'timestamp'
value_col = 'speed'

#pewna parameters
T = 30      # initialization period (in cycles)
beta = 0.5  # lower values make the algorithm behave more like regular EWMA
a = 0.99    # the maximum value of the EWMA a parameter, used for outliers
z = 3


#the PEWNA Model

# create a DataFrame for the run time variables we'll need to calculate
pewm = pd.DataFrame(index=df.index, columns=['Mean', 'Var', 'Std'], dtype=float)
pewm.iloc[0] = [df.iloc[0][value_col], 0, 0]

t = 0

for _, row in islice(df.iterrows(), 1, None):
    diff = row[value_col] - pewm.iloc[t].Mean # difference from moving average
    p = norm.pdf(diff / pewm.iloc[t].Std) if pewm.iloc[t].Std != 0 else 0 # Prob of observing diff
    a_t = a * (1 - beta * p) if t > T else 1 - 1/(t+1) # weight to give to this point
    incr = (1 - a_t) * diff

    # Update Mean, Var, Std
    pewm.iloc[t+1].Mean = pewm.iloc[t].Mean + incr
    pewm.iloc[t+1].Var = a_t * (pewm.iloc[t].Var + diff * incr)
    pewm.iloc[t+1].Std = sqrt(pewm.iloc[t+1].Var)
    t += 1
```

Comment: @Graipher Ive added dummy data to show what the df looks like.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use just raw numpy arrays for speeding it up:

after #the PEWMA Model you can just use following code:

```
_x = df[value_col]
_mean, _std, _var = np.zeros(_x.shape), np.zeros(_x.shape), np.zeros(_x.shape)

for i in range(1, len(_x)):
    diff = _x[i] - _mean[i-1]

    p = norm.pdf(diff / _std[i-1]) if _std[i-1] != 0 else 0 # Prob of observing diff
    a_t = a * (1 - beta * p) if (i-1) > T else 1 - 1/i # weight to give to this point
    incr = (1 - a_t) * diff

    # Update Mean, Var, Std
    v = a_t * (_var[i-1] + diff * incr)
    _mean[i] = _mean[i-1] + incr
    _var[i] = v
    _std[i] = np.sqrt(v)

pewm = pd.DataFrame({'Mean': _mean, 'Var': _var, 'Std': _std}, index=df.index)
```

If you need to apply it to really big data you could make it even faster by using numba package:

```
from numba import njit

# numba has some issues with stats's norm.pdf so redefine it here as function
@njit
def norm_pdf(x):
    return np.exp(-x**2/2)/np.sqrt(2*np.pi)

@njit
def pwma(_x, a, beta, T):
    _mean, _std, _var = np.zeros(_x.shape), np.zeros(_x.shape), np.zeros(_x.shape)
    _mean[0] = _x[0]

    for i in range(1, len(_x)):
        diff = _x[i] - _mean[i-1]

        p = norm_pdf(diff / _std[i-1]) if _std[i-1] != 0 else 0 # Prob of observing diff
        a_t = a * (1 - beta * p) if (i-1) > T else 1 - 1/(i) # weight to give to this point
        incr = (1 - a_t) * diff

        # Update Mean, Var, Std
        v = a_t * (_var[i-1] + diff * incr)
        _mean[i] = _mean[i-1] + incr
        _var[i] = v
        _std[i] = np.sqrt(v)
    return _mean, _var, _std

# Using :
_mean, _var, _std = pwma(df[value_col].values, 0.99, 0.5, 30)
pewm = pd.DataFrame({'Mean': _mean, 'Var': _var, 'Std': _std}, index=df.index)
```